# input not muting/pointing correctly to its new assignment in the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

sorry in advanced for the vague title..I want to input a sequence of numbers into a function and I want that function to output the ratio of the previous 2 numbers. the problem is that 'my_seq' is not changing; it just keeps its initial values..

so far my code looks like this:

```
def consecutive_elem_ratio(seq):
    temp = []
    for i,v in enumerate(seq):
        temp.append(v/seq[i-1])
    seq = temp
    seq.pop(0)

    print(seq)


my_seq = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
consecutive_elem_ratio(my_seq)
print(my_seq)
```

in the end i want print(my_seq) to output:

[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]

and not

[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128] again.

i.e I want my_seq to point to the print(seq) in the function. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that with the statement `seq = temp`, you are *assigning another object* to the variable `seq`, but not modifying the *original object* which is initially named `seq`.

One way to solve it would be to actually repopulate the list.

```
def consecutive_elem_ratio(seq):
    temp = []
    for i,v in enumerate(seq):
        temp.append(v/seq[i-1])

    for i in range(len(temp)):
        seq[i] = temp[i]  # Overwrite the elements of the list, not the list itself

    seq.pop(0)

    print(seq)
```